# ui-date-format in nggrid cell template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

I want a date picker in my cell so i have created a cell template

```
var myDateTemplate= '<input type="text"  ng-model="row.entity.myDate"  />';
```

my col model is

```
    var col = [{
                field : 'myDate',
                displayName : 'My Date',
                enableCellEdit : true,
                width : '130',
                cellTemplate : myDateTemplate,
                editableCellTemplate : myDateTemplate,
                resizable : true,
                sortable : false
            }]
```

it works fine and when i choose date i get it in mm/dd/yyyy format i want to change it to dd/mm/yyyy format to i added ui date format

```
 var myDateTemplate = '<input ui-date="{ dateFormat: 'dd mm yyyy' }" ui-date-format="dd mm yyyy" ng-model="row.entity.myDate"/>';
```

when i use ui date format it will throw a error

Error: Syntax Error: Token 'undefined' not a primary expression at column NaN of the expression [{ dateFormat:] starting at [{ dateFormat:]

and it is giving the date like

Mon Dec 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) instead of my preffered format.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're close, just escape the quotes around your date format to make the proper string:

```
var myDateTemplate = '<input ui-date="{ dateFormat: \'dd mm yyyy\' }" ui-date-format="dd mm yyyy" ng-model="row.entity.myDate"/>';
```

I'm not using the exact same cellTemplate you are (presumably your input field will work correctly once you escape the quotes). This is working for me:

```
columnDefs: [{
                field:'StartTime', 
                displayName:'Start Time', 
                cellFilter: 'date:\'MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss\'' 
            }, {
                field:'duration', displayName:'Duration'
            }, {
                field:'distance', displayName:'Distance'
            }, {
                field:'typedesc', displayName:'Type'
            }, {
                field:'Drivers', displayName:'Drivers'
            }]
```

Comment: i have similar problem on date formatting. I will receive date value like  "2016-09-01 08:14:55.467 IST". and try to convert "MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss.SSS " with cellfilter option like 
       {
      "name": "creationTimestamp",
      "type": "date",
      "cellFilter": "date:'MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss.SSS'"
    },                                                                                                                  But Still i getting output value "2016-09-01 08:14:55.467 IST". can you please help me?

Comment: The minutes must to be minuscule, otherwise you will have the month: cellFilter: 'date:\'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss\''